# SQL - Filter Data only showing changes history

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, distinct

I have a table seems like:

```
    
 | ID_Product | Product | Price |           Date            | 
------------------------------------------------------
 |     01     |  Socks  |  $20  |  2020-06-02 18:27:49.000  | 
 |     03     |  Belt   |  $30  |  2020-06-03 13:27:08.000  | 
 |     01     |  Socks  |  $20  |  2020-06-11 17:00:04.000  | 
 |     02     |  Boots  |  $40  |  2020-06-12 09:27:19.000  | 
 |     02     |  Boots  |  $40  |  2020-06-17 11:27:10.000  | 
 |     01     |  Socks  |  $25  |  2020-06-25 15:29:45.000  | 
 |     01     |  Socks  |  $28  |  2020-07-08 16:27:30.000  |
```

I need a query to get a distinct rows by price and date, to get some "history" of prices changes, just like this

```
    
 | ID_Product | Product | Price |           Date            | 
------------------------------------------------------
 |     03     |  Belt   |  $30  |  2020-06-03 13:27:08.000  | 
 |     01     |  Socks  |  $20  |  2020-06-11 17:00:04.000  | 
 |     02     |  Boots  |  $40  |  2020-06-17 11:27:10.000  | 
 |     01     |  Socks  |  $25  |  2020-06-25 15:29:45.000  | 
 |     01     |  Socks  |  $28  |  2020-07-08 16:27:30.000  |
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does "distinct rows by price and date" mean?

Comment: You will have a better experience here if you read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your questions with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips, and also [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Thank you everyone. @allmhuran Im sure i need to learn, not only this piece of cake. I didn't know lag() function.. Ty Gordon, It works as i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to just want the most recent date for each product price:

```
select product_id, price, max(date)
from t
group by product_id, price;
```

I thought you wanted to know when new prices started to be effective.  For that,
you can use `lag()` to see when the price changes -- and keep only those rows:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(price) over (partition by product_id order by date) as prev_price
      from t
     ) t
where prev_price is null or prev_price <> price;
```